Set reachable_time_ms
How can I use pyroute2 to change the base value of reachable_time_ms?
I couldn't find how to do this in the documentation on pyroute2 library.
Which object should be used from the library to set this parameter. As I understand it, you can use IPRoute for this.

You cannot directly modify the reachable_time_ms parameter using the pyroute2 library, as it is not directly exposed through the library's IPRoute or other objects. This parameter is part of the ARP (neighbor) cache settings and is typically configured at the system level using the Linux sysctl interface or by writing to /proc/sys files.
But here is how you can modify the reachable_time_ms parameter indirectly:
You can use the subprocess module to invoke the sysctl command from Python (recommended):
import subprocess

# Replace 'eth0' with your interface name
interface = "eth0"
new_value = 30000  # Reachable time in milliseconds

# Construct and execute the sysctl command
sysctl_command = f"sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.{interface}.reachable_time_ms={new_value}"
subprocess.run(sysctl_command, shell=True, check=True)

Alternatively, you can modify the corresponding file under /proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/<interface>/reachable_time_ms (not recommended):
interface = "eth0"
new_value = "30000"  # Reachable time in milliseconds

# Construct the file path
file_path = f"/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/{interface}/reachable_time_ms"

# Write the new value to the file
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(new_value)

